# Сдвиг элемента по нажатию клавиши

Tags: javascript, css

Пишу змейку.

Нужно сдвигать 4 ячейки(длина змеи) по нажатию клавиш стрелок.

У меня написано условие, но не знаю как продолжить. Каким образом можно это реализовать?

Вот код:

```js
(function() {
    var rows = '';
    for(var i=0;i<=15;i++) {
        rows += '<tr class="row" + i';
        for(var j=0;j<=25;j++) {
            rows += '<td></td>';
        }
        rows += '</tr>';
    }
    document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = rows;
  addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 86)
      document.body.style.background = "";
  });  
}());
```

```css
#table {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
td {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1) {
    background: red;
}
tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2) {
    background: red;
}
tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(3) {
    background: red;
}
tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(4) {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
   <tr class="row">
       <td></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Уберите стили с красным фоном по индексам элементов. Разве не очевидно, что Вам нужно назначать стиль с фоном динамически - кодом в `setinterval`?

Comment: @Igor можете показать на каком-нибудь примере?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
(function() {
  var tbl = document.getElementById('table');

  var rows = '';
  for (var i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
    rows += '<tr class="row" + i';
    for (var j = 0; j <= 25; j++) {
      rows += '<td></td>';
    }
    rows += '</tr>';
  }
  tbl.innerHTML = rows;

  var i = 0;
  var j = 0;
  
  function markCell(i, j) {
    //console.log(i, j);
    var old = document.querySelector("td.red");
    if (old)
      old.classList.remove("red");
    tbl.rows[i].cells[j].classList.add("red");
  }
  
  /*setInterval(function() {
    if (j >= tbl.rows[0].cells.length) {
      j = 0;
      i++;
    }
    if (i >= tbl.rows.length) {
      i = 0;
    }

    markCell(i, j);

    j++;
  }, 200);*/
  
  addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    // up - 38, down - 40, left - 37, right - 39
    //console.log(event.keyCode);
           if (event.keyCode == 38) { // up
      i--;
      if (i < 0)
        i = tbl.rows.length - 1;
    } else if (event.keyCode == 40) { // down
      i++;
      if (i >= tbl.rows.length)
        i = 0;
    } else if (event.keyCode == 37) { // left
      j--;
      if (j < 0)
        j = tbl.rows[0].cells.length - 1;
    } else if (event.keyCode == 39) { // right
      j++;
      if (j >= tbl.rows[0].cells.length)
        j = 0;
    }
    markCell(i, j);
  });    
  
  markCell(i, j);
}());
```

```css
#table {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

td {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr class="row">
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: дело в том что тут он автоматически идет, как прописать для клавиш стрелок?

Answer (score 2):

Именно сдвигать ничего не нужно. 
А нужен двумерный массив, с координатами ваших ячеек и начальная точка (голова змеи).

Еще нужен объект со свойствами и методами, а также сетИнтервал или requestAnimationFrame.

И нужен алгоритм.

Змея - это объект, ячейки змеи - свойства,  в которых объект с текущими координатами, текущим направлением и массив для сбора новых направлений (новое направление при нажатии на стрелку добавляется в конец массива, а при отрисовке берется первый элемент).

Отрисовка змеи (движение) - проходим циклом по ячейкам змеи и отрисовываем согласно координатам и текущему направлению (делается это циклично через сетИнтервал например)

Отслеживание направления (изгибы змеи) - 
 - Самое простое это каждая ячейка змеи перед отрисовкой проверяет координаты предыдущей: если к своим текущим координатам прибавить (согласно текущему направлению - или отнять единицу от X или Y), то получим ли координаты предыдущей? Если да то отрисовываем - наша змея не меняла направление. А если нет, то из массива сбора новых направлений (для этой конкретной ячейки) выбрасываем первый элемент и таким образом для отрисовки уже берется следующее направление, т.е. наша ячейка меняет направление.

Стоит учесть что выше сказанное не относится к первой ячейке, т.е. голове змеи. Голова змеи должна сразу же поменять свое направление после нажатия стрелки. Она же не может сверять свое направление с предыдущей, которой у головы нет.

Еще надо реализовать проверку на коллизии (столкновения).